# how to give ID single element inside the array of objects from the api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I already added the Id property on the array of objects from the API, but when I added oclick method and tried to console the id of a single element  all elements inside the array take the same ID, so how to give every element inside the Array of object it's unique id when I click the element.

here is my code and screenshots from the console

app.js

```js
import React from "react";
import Question from "./components/Question";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&type=multiple")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        let allTasks = json.results;

        allTasks = allTasks.map((currentTask) => {
          const id = nanoid();
          return { ...currentTask, isHeld: false, id: id };
        });
        setData(allTasks);
      });
  };

  function hold(id) {
    console.log(id);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(data);
  }, [data]);

  const Elements = data.map((quiz, index) => {
    return (
      <Question
        key={quiz.id}
        question={quiz.question}
        correct_answer={quiz.correct_answer}
        incorrect_answers={quiz.incorrect_answers}
        hold={() => hold(quiz.id)}
        isHeld={quiz.isHeld}
      />
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="allnow">{Elements}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Question.jsx

```js
import React from "react";

export default function Question(props) {
  return (
    <div className="question">
      <h2 className="question-title"> {props.question} </h2>
      <div className="wrong-answers">
        <button className="correct-answer" onClick={props.hold}>
          {props.correct_answer}
        </button>
        <button className="incorrect-answer" onClick={props.hold}>
          {props.incorrect_answers}
        </button>
        <button className="incorrect-answer" onClick={props.hold}>
          {props.incorrect_answers}
        </button>

  
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: screenshot from the console]

Comment: _"array of objects"_: your API is only returning an object with _one_ object in its `results` array (`amount=1`). How are you getting an array of _objects_?

Comment: Please fix your code section of Question.jsx in the question, it's broken

Comment: Are you asking how to give each answer (both correct/incorrect) its own id? Are you simply trying to determine if the clicked button is the correct answer? That wouldn't be difficult as the correct answer will always be the first button...

Comment: results have  an array of objects.  and I added an Id, the elements inside the results like (correct_answer), (incorrect_answer) i want to assign  them a unique id  when ever i click them

Comment: @Andy yes that's what I want. but the incorrect answer also has to have a unique id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key appears to be also using `map` to iterate over the `incorrect_answers`. When you do that you can call `nanoid` (I've had to use a random number generator - `rnd()` - here because `nanoid` wouldn't work in the snippet), and then apply that id to each answer.

Note 1) I've used [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) rather than applying the random id to an HTML id - personal preference. You can access them through the element's [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property.

Note 2) I have swapped things around a little just to understand what you wrote, but the important code is in the `Question` component, and in the `hold` function.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function rnd() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
}

function App() {
  
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  function addIds(data) {
    return data.map((currentTask) => {
      const id = rnd();
      return { id, ...currentTask, isHeld: false };
    });
  }

  function fetchData(endpoint) {
    fetch(endpoint)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const tasks = addIds(data.results);
        setData(tasks);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const endpoint = 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&type=multiple';
    fetchData(endpoint);
  }, []);

  function hold(e) {
    console.log(e.target.dataset.id);
  }

  function buildElements(data) {
    
    return data.map(quiz => {
      
      const {
        question,
        correct_answer,
        incorrect_answers,
        isHeld
      } = quiz;
      
      return (
        <Question
          question={question}
          correct_answer={correct_answer}
          incorrect_answers={incorrect_answers}
          hold={hold}
          isHeld={isHeld}
        />
      );

    });
  }

  if (!data.length) return <div />;

  return (
    <div className="app">
      {buildElements(data)}
    </div>
  );

}

function Question(props) {
  
  const {
    hold,
    question,
    correct_answer,
    incorrect_answers,
    isHeld
  } = props;

  return (

    <div>
      
      <h2 className="question-title">{question}</h2>
      
      <button
        data-id={rnd()}
        className="correct-answer"
        onClick={hold}
      >{correct_answer}
      </button>
      
      <div className="wrong-answers">
        {incorrect_answers.map(ia => {
          const id = rnd();
          return (
            <button
              key={id}
              data-id={id}
              className="incorrect-answer"
              onClick={hold}
            >{ia}
            </button>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    
    </div>
  
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: it worked for me and it solved my issue smoothly thanks andy.